# SQL Server User define function giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I Create the below UDF IN SQL Server

```
CREATE Function [Fn_dd]
(@InputstartDate Date, @InputendDate Date)
returns @AllDates Table
    (AllDate Date)
As
Begin
    Declare @startDate date
    Declare @endDate date
    Declare @rDate date
    set @startDate  = @InputstartDate
    set @EndDate  = @InputendDate

    while (@startDate <=  @endDate)
    Begin
        insert into @AllDates values (@startDate )
        set @startDate = DATEADD(dd,1,@startDate)
    End
return
End
GO
```

But when I use it in my data it gives an error

```
select
 dbo.Fn_dd('2020-01-02','2020-02-08')
from dbo.Txns
```

error message

```
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Fn_dd", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: I strongly suggest against that function anyway. It's a multi-line table value function, which are known to perform poorly, and it uses a `WHILE`, which *does* perform terribly. Use an inline table value function with a Tally, or `JOIN` to your calendar table.

Comment: You select from a function the same as if it were a table. your syntax is wrong

Comment: `DATEADD(dd,1,@startDate)` You save nothing using "dd" rather than "day" but the latter is far more readable. But why reinvent the wheel? Just search "calendar table" for code that dynamically generates a series of dates in a much more optimized fashion (or create a static calendar table once and never need to address this issue again).

Comment: You're treating your function as if it were a scalar-valued function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function returns a table. You cannot use it in `SELECT`; you must use it in `FROM`:

`select * FROM dbo.Fn_dd('2020-01-02','2020-02-08')`